# PHP preg_split() if it is NOT a number, + sign, bracket, new line or tab

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation, regex-look-ahead

I have the following operation which splits a string whenever it encounters an alphabet:

```
$splitOriginal = preg_split("/[a-zA-Z]/", implode('', array_slice($array, $key)), 2);
```

I want to extend it in such a way that it splits the string whenever the variable encountered is NOT a number, bracket, plus sign, hyphen, newline or tab.

I have written a regex which can match the above:

```
preg_match('/^(?=.*[0-9])[- +()0-9\r\n\t]+$/', $value)
```

But I need to negate it, to match whenever the value being compared is NOT it. Would really appreciate any prompt help I can get.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show a sample input, as well as what the resulting array should be?

Comment: Looks like you should just use `'/[^\d()+\n\t-]/'` with `preg_split`. Why did you switch to `preg_match`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew didn't switch to `preg_match`, was just trying to show the other regex I attempted to use. Thanks for the input, will try it out.

Comment: @ChrisHaas sample input is any string that contains both alphabets, numbers and symbols. Should count from the beginning and split whenever it encounters a character that is NOT a number, bracket, plus sign, hyphen, newline or tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[a-zA-Z]` pattern matches any ASCII letter. Any char "*NOT a number, bracket, plus sign, hyphen, newline or tab*" can also be a letter, so you should focus on the latter requirement, your former pattern is no longer relevant.

You should keep using `preg_split`:

```php
$splitOriginal = preg_split('/[^\d()+\n\t-]/', implode('', array_slice($array, $key)), 2);
```

The `[^\d()+\n\t-]` pattern matches exactly what you formulated. Pay attention at the hyphen, when it is at the end (or start) of the character class, it can go unescaped.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do I add space to the expression as well?

Comment: @user627341 `'/[^\d()+\n\t -]/'`. Or maybe just use `'/[^\d()+\s-]/'`. Or even `'/[^\d()+\s-]+/u'`.